# Editing a csv file in Python3

Tags: python, csv, data-wrangling

Hello I am a little new to editing csv files with python. I am working on a project. This is a simple grade calculator that reads in a csv file called new_grade.csv . My script calculates the average grade for each student. I accidently hardcoded my script and I was having trouble reading in multiple csv lines.
My question is how do I modify my code to run an arbitrary line of data. My code only does to first line of data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My csv file:

```
Smithy, James, 100, 78, 92, 92, 85, 85, 95, 100, 75, 85, 50, 85, 87, 95, 95, 80, 80, 96, 95, 95, 95, 85, 79, 95, 85, 95, A, A+, A, B, A+, F, C, B, A, A, A, A, 85, 95, 82, 91
Gadget, John, 0, 0, 92, 92, 85, 60, 85, 100, 75, 85, 50, 85, 0, 95, 85, 70, 70, 0, 95, 95, 95, 85, 0, 95, 0, 95, F, F, F, B, A+, A, C, B, C, F, F, F, 45, 75, 82, 31
Phillips, David, 100, 78, 92, 92, 85, 90, 85, 100, 75, 85, 50, 85, 87, 95, 85, 80, 80, 96, 95, 95, 95, 85, 79, 95, 85, 95, A, A+, A, B, A+, A, A, B, C, A, A, A, 85, 95, 82, 91
```

My code that can solve one line of data:

```
def main():
    try:
        import csv
        import sys
        # This section opens up the file grades.csv. It will then read the data and then takes that data and converts
        # that data into a list. When it's in a list we can splice the data to compute averages.
        with open("new_grade.csv", 'r') as f:
            list(csv.reader(f))  # had data = variable

        while True:
            # function to remove \n character from csv file
            def remove_newlines(fname):
                flist = open(fname).readlines()
                return [s.rstrip('\n') for s in flist]

            old_line = (remove_newlines("new_grade.csv"))
            # For required output:
            line = old_line[0].split(', ')  # This open up the line of the file. For instance this opens up line 1 of
            # file.
            if len(line) > 44:  # This checks to make sure that the data doesn't exceed 44 indexes
                print('The data in your file exceeds the maximum amount. Check line 1 of your file. ')
                sys.exit(1)

            def student():
                print((line[0]) + ',' + ' ' + (line[1]), end=', ')  # This finds the student's name

            def preparation_assignment_average():  # This will compute the preparation assignment average.
                global prep
                prep = 0
                for i in (line[2:16]):
                    i = int(i)
                    if 0 <= i <= 100:  # This is checking to make sure that the grades are in the range 0-100
                        prep = prep + int(i)
                    else:  # if it is not in the range of 0-100 it will print this statement and end the program
                        print('One of the values that you entered is not valid. Please enter a grade within the '
                              'range 0-100, Error\noccurred on line 1 in text file.')
                        sys.exit(1)  # This ends the program if it fails the if statement
                print(round((prep / 14), 2), end=', ')

            def lab_score_average():  # This will compute the lab score average
                global lab
                lab = 0
                for i in (line[17:28]):
                    i = int(i)
                    if 0 <= i <= 100:  # This is checking to make sure that the grades are in the range 0-100
                        lab = lab + int(i)
                    else:  # if it is not in the range of 0-100 it will print this statement and end the program
                        print('One of the values that you entered is not valid. Please enter a grade within the '
                              'range 0-100, Error\noccurred on line 1 in text file.')
                        sys.exit(1)  # This ends the program if it fails the if statement
                print(round((lab / 12), 2), end=', ')

            def post_lab_average():  # This calculates the post lab average of the student. It takes a letter and
                # converts the letter to a score that is an integer.
                global score
                score = 0
                for i in (line[28:39]):
                    if i == "A+":
                        score += 100
                    elif i == "A":
                        score += 95
                    elif i == "A-":
                        score += 90
                    elif i == "B":
                        score += 85
                    elif i == "C":
                        score += 75
                    elif i == "D":
                        score += 60
                    elif i == "F":
                        score += 0
                    elif i is not "A+" or "A" or "A-" or "B" or "C" or "D" or "F":
                        print('Your file is not formatted to the standard of the program. On line 1 of your file, '
                              'you have\na score where a letter grade should be. Please check file and rerun the '
                              'program.')
                        sys.exit(1)
                print(round((score / 12), 2), end=', ')

            def exam_average():  # This will compute the exam average for the student
                global exam
                exam = 0
                for i in (line[40:44]):
                    i = int(i)
                    if 0 <= i <= 100:  # This is checking to make sure that the grades are in the range 0-100
                        exam = exam + int(i)
                    else:  # if it is not in the range of 0-100 it will print this statement and end the program
                        print('One of the values that you entered is not valid. Please enter a grade within the '
                              'range 0-100, Error\noccurred on line 1 in text file.')
                        sys.exit(1)  # This ends the program if it fails the if statement
                print(round((exam / 4), 2), end=', ')

            def overall_weighted_class_average():  # This will compute the overall class average for the student
                global weighted_class_grade
                global weighted_prep
                global weighted_lab
                global weighted_score
                global weighted_exam
                weighted_prep = ((prep / 14) * .10)  # This is calculating the weighted average for a
                weighted_lab = ((lab / 12) * .20)  # This is calculating the weighted average for b
                weighted_score = ((score / 12) * .10)  # This is calculating the weighted average for score
                weighted_exam = ((exam / 4) * .60)  # This is calculating the weighted average for exam
                weighted_class_grade = round((weighted_prep + weighted_lab + weighted_score + weighted_exam), 2)
                print(weighted_class_grade, end=', ')

            def letter_grade_for_class():  # This will take the weighted class grade and it will print that grade
                # according to the range
                letter = weighted_class_grade
                while True:
                    if 95 < letter <= 100:
                        print("A+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 95:
                        print("A")
                        break
                    elif 90 <= letter <= 94:
                        print("A-")
                        break
                    elif 85 < letter <= 89:
                        print("B+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 85:
                        print("B")
                        break
                    elif 80 <= letter <= 84:
                        print("B-")
                        break
                    elif 75 < letter <= 79:
                        print("C+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 75:
                        print("C")
                        break
                    elif 70 <= letter <= 74:
                        print("C-")
                        break
                    elif 65 < letter <= 69:
                        print("D+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 65:
                        print("D")
                        break
                    elif 60 <= letter <= 64:
                        print("D-")
                        break
                    elif letter <= 59:
                        print("F")
                        break

            def call_functions():  # This takes all the definitions and makes it into one definition
                student()
                preparation_assignment_average()
                lab_score_average()
                post_lab_average()
                exam_average()
                overall_weighted_class_average()
                letter_grade_for_class()
                return ''

            break
        # After computing all the averages for the line of data it then writes it to a new file
        original_stdout = sys.stdout
        file = open('test_file.csv', 'x')  # The x will not save the file if it already exists
        sys.stdout = file
        for i in call_functions():
            file.writelines('\n%s' % i)
            sys.stdout = original_stdout
            file.close()
        f.close()
        
      except ValueError:  # displays when one of the letters is out of its index
        print('Sorry, one of the letters in the file is out of place. Please check the file again to make sure that \n'
              'the letter is not where the numbers are supposed to be. Check indexes 29-39. That is where the \n'
              'letter grades for the file should be.')
        sys.exit(1)
    except FileNotFoundError:  # displays error if there is no file by that name
        print("Sorry, the current file that you have selected is not a File.")
        sys.exit(1)
    except IndexError:  # this displays when there is no data in the file
        print('The file that you have selected does not contain any grades. Please check the file again.')
        sys.exit(1)
    except PermissionError:
        print('The file that you are trying to save is already a file. The file is protected and can not be written.')
        sys.exit(1)
    except FileExistsError:
        print('The file that you are trying to save is already a file. Please rename your file or delete that file '
              'and rerun the program.')
        sys.exit(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you posted a whole python project?

Comment: yes, my script i posted will compute the first line of the csv file. line = old_line[0].split(', ')  this line of code reads in line 1 of the csv file. I was having trouble reading multiple lines of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two things which explain the behavior you're seeing and hint at ways you can modify your code.

1. The line `line = old_line[0].split(', ')` indicates that you are only reading the very first line of the file. You should have some sort of loop which accesses each line of the file as `line = old_line[index].split(',')`.
2. The following loop likely doesn't do what you think it does:

```
for i in call_functions():
    file.writelines('\n%s' % i)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout
    file.close()
```

The `call_functions()` method actually returns an empty string, so the body of this loop actually doesn't run at all. `call_functions()` is only called once and is the reason you're only seeing one row of output in your output csv. You need to call `call_functions()` for each row in the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lengthy post so I'll break it down in parts to make it more readable. The full code is at the end following the explanations for the changes.

**Part I**

I copied and pasted your code and both PyCharm and Visual Studio caught a SyntaxWarning error on line 72 for your `post_lab_average()` function.

This is the `elif` statement that triggers it:

```
elif i is not "A+" or "A" or "A-" or "B" or "C" or "D" or "F":
```

The program just wants you to change `is not` to `!=` but you honestly don't need an expression here since you are already going to check for all the other letters. You only really need an `else:` instead of `elif i != 'A+' or 'A' or ...`

After making all the other changes I'm about to explain, the program runs into a problem in this section again where `if i == "A+":` wont work if there's extra space in the line it's checking, ie `i = " A+"`. To fix that issues we reword the expression to `if "A+" in i:` which allows us to check for `"A+"` regardless if there's an extra space or not.

Your `post_lab_average()` ought to look like this:

```
def post_lab_average():

    global score
    score = 0
    for i in (line[28:39]):
        if "A+" in i:
            score += 100
        elif "A" in i:
            score += 95
        elif "A-" in i:
            score += 90
        elif "B" in i:
            score += 85
        elif "C" in i:
            score += 75
        elif "D" in i:
            score += 60
        elif "F" in i:
            score += 0
        else:
            print('Your file is not formatted to the standard of the program. On line 1 of your file, '
                  'you have\na score where a letter grade should be. Please check file and rerun the '
                  'program.')
            exit(1)
```

Also, throughout your code you call `sys.exit(1)` to terminate the program, the `sys.` is unnecessary and using just `exit(1)` will work fine.

**Part II**

The next error that pops up is the exception, `FileExistsError` for the line

```
file = open('test_file.csv', 'x')
```

In the end, we will be appending data to the csv file so we're going to include this line of code at the start of your `main()` function:

```
import os

try:
    os.remove('test_file.csv')
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

This will always remove the file if it exists, and you can delete your `except FileExistsError:` at the end since the exception will no longer trigger.

**Part III**

When opening files using `with open()` the default setting is to read the file so you do not need to add the `'r'` You actually don't need the function `remove_newlines()` and we're going to open the file and assign the data to a list like so:

```
with open('new_grade.csv') as file:
    student_list = list(csv.reader(file))
```

**Part IV**

Now we're going to adjust your `while True` loop to run with a counter, stopping when it has run through all the lists.

```
count = 0
while count < len(student_list):
    line = student_list[count]
    count += 1
```

The loop will continue until it has run through all the sub-lists in `student_list`. You will have to get rid of your `break` at the end of the loop for this to work.

**Part V**

Almost done! Running the file in its current state will produce a file with only the last student in its entries. To fix that we will indent the block of code that writes the file so that it will run at the end of every loop rather than after the loop has finished. I also reformatted to use `with open('a')` so we can append our data rather than overwrite.

```
original_stdout = sys.stdout
with open('test_file.csv', 'a') as file:
    sys.stdout = file
    for i in call_functions():
        file.writelines('\n%s' % i)
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

**Final Code**

```
def main():
    try:
        import csv
        import sys
        import os

        # Checks if file exists and removes it if found
        try:
            os.remove('test_file.csv')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

        # Opens the data file and assigns it to a list
        with open('new_grade.csv') as file:
            student_list = list(csv.reader(file))

        # Loops through each student in list
        count = 0
        while count < len(student_list):
            line = student_list[count]
            count += 1

            if len(line) > 44:  # This checks to make sure that the data doesn't exceed 44 indexes
                print('The data in your file exceeds the maximum amount. Check line 1 of your file. ')
                sys.exit(1)

            def student():
                print((line[0]) + ',' + ' ' + (line[1]), end=', ')  # This finds the student's name

            def preparation_assignment_average():  # This will compute the preparation assignment average.
                global prep
                prep = 0
                for i in (line[2:16]):
                    i = int(i)
                    if 0 <= i <= 100:  # This is checking to make sure that the grades are in the range 0-100
                        prep = prep + int(i)
                    else:  # if it is not in the range of 0-100 it will print this statement and end the program
                        print('One of the values that you entered is not valid. Please enter a grade within the '
                              'range 0-100, Error\noccurred on line 1 in text file.')
                        exit(1)  # This ends the program if it fails the if statement
                print(round((prep / 14), 2), end=', ')

            def lab_score_average():  # This will compute the lab score average
                global lab
                lab = 0
                for i in (line[17:28]):
                    i = int(i)
                    if 0 <= i <= 100:  # This is checking to make sure that the grades are in the range 0-100
                        lab = lab + int(i)
                    else:  # if it is not in the range of 0-100 it will print this statement and end the program
                        print('One of the values that you entered is not valid. Please enter a grade within the '
                              'range 0-100, Error\noccurred on line 1 in text file.')
                        exit(1)  # This ends the program if it fails the if statement
                print(round((lab / 12), 2), end=', ')

            def post_lab_average():  # This calculates the post lab average of the student. It takes a letter and
                # converts the letter to a score that is an integer.
                global score
                score = 0
                for i in (line[28:39]):
                    if "A+" in i:
                        score += 100
                    elif "A" in i:
                        score += 95
                    elif "A-" in i:
                        score += 90
                    elif "B" in i:
                        score += 85
                    elif "C" in i:
                        score += 75
                    elif "D" in i:
                        score += 60
                    elif "F" in i:
                        score += 0
                    else:
                        print('Your file is not formatted to the standard of the program. On line 1 of your file, '
                              'you have\na score where a letter grade should be. Please check file and rerun the '
                              'program.')
                        exit(1)
                print(round((score / 12), 2), end=', ')

            def exam_average():  # This will compute the exam average for the student
                global exam
                exam = 0
                for i in (line[40:44]):
                    i = int(i)
                    if 0 <= i <= 100:  # This is checking to make sure that the grades are in the range 0-100
                        exam = exam + int(i)
                    else:  # if it is not in the range of 0-100 it will print this statement and end the program
                        print('One of the values that you entered is not valid. Please enter a grade within the '
                              'range 0-100, Error\noccurred on line 1 in text file.')
                        exit(1)  # This ends the program if it fails the if statement
                print(round((exam / 4), 2), end=', ')

            def overall_weighted_class_average():  # This will compute the overall class average for the student
                global weighted_class_grade
                global weighted_prep
                global weighted_lab
                global weighted_score
                global weighted_exam
                weighted_prep = ((prep / 14) * .10)  # This is calculating the weighted average for a
                weighted_lab = ((lab / 12) * .20)  # This is calculating the weighted average for b
                weighted_score = ((score / 12) * .10)  # This is calculating the weighted average for score
                weighted_exam = ((exam / 4) * .60)  # This is calculating the weighted average for exam
                weighted_class_grade = round((weighted_prep + weighted_lab + weighted_score + weighted_exam), 2)
                print(weighted_class_grade, end=', ')

            def letter_grade_for_class():  # This will take the weighted class grade and it will print that grade
                # according to the range
                letter = weighted_class_grade
                while True:
                    if 95 < letter <= 100:
                        print("A+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 95:
                        print("A")
                        break
                    elif 90 <= letter <= 94:
                        print("A-")
                        break
                    elif 85 < letter <= 89:
                        print("B+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 85:
                        print("B")
                        break
                    elif 80 <= letter <= 84:
                        print("B-")
                        break
                    elif 75 < letter <= 79:
                        print("C+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 75:
                        print("C")
                        break
                    elif 70 <= letter <= 74:
                        print("C-")
                        break
                    elif 65 < letter <= 69:
                        print("D+")
                        break
                    elif letter == 65:
                        print("D")
                        break
                    elif 60 <= letter <= 64:
                        print("D-")
                        break
                    elif letter <= 59:
                        print("F")
                        break

            def call_functions():  # This takes all the definitions and makes it into one definition
                student()
                preparation_assignment_average()
                lab_score_average()
                post_lab_average()
                exam_average()
                overall_weighted_class_average()
                letter_grade_for_class()
                return ''

            # After computing all the averages for the line of data it then writes it to a new file
            original_stdout = sys.stdout
            with open('test_file.csv', 'a') as file:
                sys.stdout = file
                for i in call_functions():
                    file.writelines('\n%s' % i)
                    sys.stdout = original_stdout

    except ValueError:  # displays when one of the letters is out of its index
        print('Sorry, one of the letters in the file is out of place. Please check the file again to make sure that \n'
              'the letter is not where the numbers are supposed to be. Check indexes 29-39. That is where the \n'
              'letter grades for the file should be.')
        exit(1)
    except FileNotFoundError:  # displays error if there is no file by that name
        print("Sorry, the current file that you have selected is not a File.")
        exit(1)
    except IndexError:  # this displays when there is no data in the file
        print('The file that you have selected does not contain any grades. Please check the file again.')
        exit(1)
    except PermissionError:  # this displays when you have the file open
        print('The file that you are trying to open is already open. Close the file and restart the program.')
        exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```